# Xamarin Android TextColor property behaving weirdly on different devices

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin

So within my app when it comes to labels and text on buttons etc. my colours always seem to act up. For example: if I take this label

```
<label Text="Hello World" TextColor="Blue"></Label>
```

On my phone, Samsung S9+, this will show up with a fill of black and very thin white outline, however, on another Android device, Samsung S7, this shows up as intended, being blue text. The only colours I've been able to get to work on both devices are black and white. This is the same for buttons. If I have a button with any text colours other than black or white, the text won't take the colour I'm choosing.

Background colours seems to work okay on both devices, I can have a blue background on a button and have it appear on both the S7 and my phone, it's just when it comes to text colours it starts to mess up. Any ideas?

Here is an example of what I'm saying. This label should be dark gray.

Samsung S7
[image: Label from Samsung S7]

Samsung S9+

[image: Label from Samsung S9+]

Comment: Can you give me a visual representation of what is wrong because I have never seen this issue before?

Comment: Hi @G.hakim I've added some images displaying this issue I'm having

Comment: Seems like that is your default font!

Comment: Strangely enough, after my phone updated to Android 9 this issue seems to have resolved itself? I'm not entirely sure how but it's now listening to the colours I'm defining etc.

Comment: This could be an os issue and might have nothing to do with us you know

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading the Android OS to Android Version 9 i.e. **API 28  solved the issue**